# Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3 in VS Code after running my flutter project I saw in my build tools folder the version is 33.0.2

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I uninstalled android studio because I have 4GB RAM laptop , so now I want to learn flutter in vs code I downloaded command line tools , sdk manager but this problem "Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3 in VS Code" every answer is of android studio but I want answer for VS code .

I want to run successfully my flutter project in my android device .

Answer (score 0):

It was very simple go to your sdk folder in the terminal with the help of "cd"

then run the following command: sdkmanager "build-tools;30.0.3".

this will install the version 30.03.3 of build tools .Then press f5 and run your main.dart file .